# How to Fix QStatusBar that stops to work if placed it in Layout?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qgridlayout, qstatusbar

I succeeded to moved the QStatusBar to a specific location (repositioning), but when I hover I don't see the tips anymore. I tried QStatusBar`.show()` or `.setVisible(True)` but doesn't still work. How would you approach this. Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <widget name="__qt_fake_top_level">
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="greetBTN">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>70</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="statusTip">
    <string>Greeting people,...</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>greet</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="gridLayoutWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>40</y>
     <width>241</width>
     <height>80</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_status"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="closeBTN">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>160</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="statusTip">
    <string>About to close</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>close</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
</ui>
```

### converted to Python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PySide5.QtCore import *
from PySide5.QtGui import *
from PySide5.QtWidgets import *

class Ui_AppMainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, AppMainWindow):
        if not AppMainWindow.objectName():
            AppMainWindow.setObjectName(u"AppMainWindow")
        AppMainWindow.resize(303, 190)
        self.centralwidget = QWidget(AppMainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.greetBTN = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.greetBTN.setObjectName(u"greetBTN")
        self.greetBTN.setGeometry(QRect(70, 10, 75, 24))
        self.closeBTN = QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.closeBTN.setObjectName(u"closeBTN")
        self.closeBTN.setGeometry(QRect(160, 10, 75, 24))
        self.gridLayoutWidget = QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName(u"gridLayoutWidget")
        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QRect(30, 40, 241, 80))
        self.gridLayout_status = QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout_status.setObjectName(u"gridLayout_status")
        self.gridLayout_status.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        AppMainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QStatusBar(AppMainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(u"statusbar")
        AppMainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(AppMainWindow)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(AppMainWindow)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, AppMainWindow):
        AppMainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("AppMainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(statustip)
        self.greetBTN.setStatusTip(QCoreApplication.translate("AppMainWindow", u"Greeting people,...", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(statustip)
        self.greetBTN.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("AppMainWindow", u"greet", None))
#if QT_CONFIG(statustip)
        self.closeBTN.setStatusTip(QCoreApplication.translate("AppMainWindow", u"About to close", None))
#endif // QT_CONFIG(statustip)
        self.closeBTN.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("AppMainWindow", u"close", None))
    # retranslateUi
```

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtGui import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *

class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('Xuntitled.ui', self)
        

        self.statusbar.setVisible(True)
        self.statusbar.setStyleSheet('Background:red;')

        self.statusbar.setParent(self)
        #self.statusbar.showMessage('sqddsfdsfd') # works but if I hover, nothing !
        self.statusbar.move(50, 25)

        self.gridLayout_status.addWidget(self.statusbar, 1, 1)
        
        self.show()
        

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Don't add the layout from the widget box, that's for *nested* layouts. You must set a main layout for the central widget. See the documentation about [Using layouts in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html). Besides, if you want a custom status bar placed elsewhere, then you need to add it to the layout by code and not use the default one.

Comment: @musicamante, yes want to add elsewhere, also tried var = QStatusBar() but when i QMainWindow.setStatusBar(var) ` i have issues to `send or display the statusTips / infos into this new QStatusBar located elsewhere e.g.: var.move(50, 50) `

Comment: Then you don't need a status bar, but to implement the behavior with an appropriate widget. Note that you tagged the question for PyQt5, but in your code you used very confusing imports: you must be more careful with those, and also remember that PySide and PyQt **cannot** be used together. Besides, if you use the `uic` module (which only exists for PyQt, not for PySide), there is absolutely no need to compile the ui files with the pyuic command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected behavior of a status bar is to be shown on the bottom margin of the window, allowing temporary messages and also providing an internal layout for "extra widgets" displayed in it.

If you want to show the status tip somewhere else, then you probably don't need a QStatusBar at all, and a basic QLabel will suffice.

The only requirement is to override the [`event()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#event) function of the window and check for `StatusTip` events.

In the following example I assumed that you don't really need the default status bar (so you should remove it from Designer and update the generated uic file accordingly if you use that approach).

```py
class Ui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('Xuntitled.ui', self)
        self.fakeStatusBar = QLabel()
        self.gridLayout_status.addWidget(self.fakeStatusBar)
        
    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == event.StatusTip:
            self.fakeStatusBar.setText(event.tip())
            return True
        return super().event(event)
```